# redis-collections basestring error

Tags: python-3.x, redis

Am using [redis-collections](https://redis-collections.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) version 0.1.5 with python3.4 but its throwing `basestring` errors.

```
>>>from redis_collections import Dict 
>>>d = Dict()
>>>d['answer'] = 42
>>>d

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                              
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                              
  File "/home/lukik/venv/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis_collections/base.py", line 296, in __repr__                                       
    data = self._repr_data(self._data())                                                                                                           
  File "/home/lukik/venv/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis_collections/dicts.py", line 171, in _data                                         
    return [(k, self._unpickle(v)) for (k, v) in result]                                                                                           
  File "/home/lukik/venv/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis_collections/dicts.py", line 171, in <listcomp>                                    
    return [(k, self._unpickle(v)) for (k, v) in result]                                                                                           
  File "/home/lukik/venv/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/redis_collections/base.py", line 225, in _unpickle                                      
    if not isinstance(string, basestring):                                                                                                         
NameError: name 'basestring' is not defined
```

Looks like a python3 compatibility issue yet in github it looks like that was [resolved](https://github.com/honzajavorek/redis-collections/pull/22)